# Using fold expression to construct a trivial object

Tags: c++, constructor, tuples, c++17, fold

I am trying to construct an object using `std::apply` and fold expressions. From what I can tell reading documentation online, folding on the comma should work. Here is an example to clarify.

```
struct my_pair final {
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct test final {
    my_pair back() {
        return std::apply(
                [](auto&... vector) {
                    return my_pair{ (vector.back(), ...) }; },
                data);
    }

    std::tuple<std::vector<float>, std::vector<float>> data
            = { { 0.f }, { 1.f } };
};
```

I unpack the tuple, get the last elements and try to return a new object using the elements.

Various compilers complain `y` is never initialized. Somehow expansion is not taking place. At least, not how I would expect.

```
error: missing field
      'y' initializer [-Werror,-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  ...[](auto&... vector) { return my_pair{ (vector.back(), ...) }; },
                                                                ^
```

If I disable -Werror, the first value of `my_pair` is 1, the second is 0. I tried using unary left fold, but the results where identical.

It seems like this should work, cppreference has this vector `push_back` example which looks similar (from my perspective).

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void push_back_vec(std::vector<T>& v, Args&&... args)
{
    (v.push_back(args), ...);
}
```

Is it possible to create a trivial (pod) type object using fold expressions? If so, from an unpacked tuple?

Comment: Remember that a fold expression is still an expression. `y` is initialized by the second expression and you have one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a fold expression here. The correct code is:

```
[](auto&... vector) 
{
    return my_pair{vector.back()...}; 
}
```

---

With your existing code, this is the expansion that occurs:

```
return my_pair{ (0.f, 1.f) }
```

The first element if being initialized with `(0.f, 1.f)`, which evaluates to `1.f`. In this case, the comma token is a *comma operator* - it is not separating the arguments during aggregate initialization.

Comment: Haha awesome, ty! Wasn't expecting such an easy fix :)